# Convert vti image file to vtk with python?

Tags: python, vtk

I know that i can convert using paraview but I want to convert vti format to vtk using python, can someone help me ?

Comment: Hi, please take a minute to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question.

Comment: What did you try so far? You should use vtkMarchingCubes to convert vtkImageData to vtkPolyData if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: i tried this code and it works

import vtk
reader = vtk.vtkXMLImageDataReader()
reader.SetFileName("input.vti")
reader.Update()
image = reader.GetOutput()
writer = vtk.vtkDataSetWriter()
writer.SetFileName("output.vtk")
writer.SetInputData(image)
writer.Write()